# the point where all functional are non zero

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let $\{f_n\}$ be sequence of non zero bounded linear functionals on a Banach space X. Show that there is  $x\in X$ so that $f_n(x)\ne0$, for all $n\in \Bbb N$.

I am confused, non zero functional means on set of non zero measure the functional is non zero? I have tried so idea but does not work. I am really confused which theorem from Banach space is used here.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: there doesn't need to be any measure on your space. non-zero functional just means that it's not identically equal to $0$, i.e. for each $f_n$ there exists $x_n \in X$ s.t. $f_n(x_n) \not= 0$

Comment: thanks for clearing my confusion. Could you please give me some hints to start up..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem $\;$

Comment: @Ricky, Baire category is used here? i don't see how i link up with Baire category. please write me some lines...

Comment: Another way to phrase the problem is: Show $X\ne\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \text{ker}(f_n)$. The kernel of a bounded linear functional is closed. Show the kernel of a non-zero bounded linear functional is nowhere dense (does not contain an open ball).

Comment: @David i am not able to show ker(fn) is nowhere dense.yes, once it is shown then i am done. Could you please show for me.

Comment: The kernel of $f$ is a subspace of $X$. If it contained an open ball $B$, then taking $x\in B$, the open set $C=x-B$ would be a subset of  the kernel. So is any scalar multiple of $C$ ...

Comment: @David, $x-B$ is just empty set, isn't it? Do u mean $ker(fn)-B$, I am sorry, i'm confused

Comment: No. I mean assume $\ker(f)$ contains an open ball $B$. Take $x\in B$ and set $C=\{ x-y:y\in B\}$. $C$ is just a translate of $B$ that contains $0$. $C$ is still open so it contains an open ball centered at $0$. $C$ is still a subset of the linear space $\text{ker}(f)$; so, $f(x)=0$ for all $y$ in an open ball centered at $0$. This implies $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in X$. So $f$ is the zero functional.

Comment: @David, I'm sorry, I am still confused, why f is identically zero on X when it is zero in open set centered at $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the claim is not true. Then every $x\in X$ belongs to $\ker f_n$ for some $n$. Thus
$$
X = \cup_{i=1}^n \ker f_n.
$$
By Baire category theorem, one of the closed sets $\ker f_n$ has non-empty interior. Let $k$ be such that $\ker f_k$ has non-empty interior. 
Let $x_0\in \ker f_k$ and $\rho>0$ such that $B_\rho(x_0) \subset \ker f_k$.
This ball is translated into the origin: For each $x\in B_\rho(x_0)$ the point $x-x_0\in B_\rho(0)$ is in $\ker f_k$. This proves
$$
B_\rho(0)\in \ker f_k.
$$ 
It remains to show $f_k=0$. Take $y\in X$, $y\ne 0$. Then $\frac{\rho}{2\|y\|}y\in B_\rho(0)$ and
$$
f_k(y) = \frac{2\|y\|}\rho f_k\left( \frac{\rho}{2\|y\|}y\right)=0.
$$
Hence, $f_k(y)=0$ for all $y\in X$, which implies $f_k=0$. A contradiction.